Open JDK (Corretto) components license
Corretto is licensed under GPLv2 with CPE.
However some of its components are licensed under BSD, CDDL, CC0, GPL without CPE etc.
I am trying to understand how that works, does GPL overrides the other licenses?
I need to redistribute Corretto with my Java application, does that matter to me?

I'm terribly sorry to ask, but "CPE"?

It stands for Classpath exception

Thank you; understood.

OpenJDK depends on and links to many third party components as can be found on this page, for e.g. libffi (licensed under MIT), alsa-lib (licensed under LGPLv2.1), X11 (licensed under BSD).
I'm not sure if any of those third party components are licensed under GPLv2. So far, they don't appear to be.
OpenJDK itself is licensed under GPLv2 with the Classpath Exception (CPE).
The Classpath Exception allows you to license your software that uses OpenJDK, under terms of your choice (including as commercial proprietary software). Without it, you would have to license your software under GPLv2.
When third party components are linked to OpenJDK, the licenses of both OpenJDK (GPLv2) and those third party components (like MIT for libffi) are binding upon the licensee of OpenJDK (i.e. you), for those third party components.
For this reason, only third party components with licenses that are compatible with GPLv2 may be linked to OpenJDK. For e.g. LGPLv2.1 and MIT licenses are both compatible with GPLv2.
By fulfilling the conditions of GPLv2 + CPE, you would also fulfill the conditions of those compatible licenses. That's what license compatibility essentially means.
If you read the conditions of the MIT license, and compare it with GPLv2 + CPE, you will find that when you fulfill all the conditions of GPLv2 + CPE, you would also fulfill all the conditions of the MIT license.
In some cases, licenses like MPL2 provide compatibility with GPLv2 by foregoing its own conditions when MPL2-licensed software is linked to a larger program licensed under GPLv2.

It appears that the license of the components do not matter according to this paragraph from the OpenJDK website:

As a special exception, the copyright holders of this library give you
permission to link  this library with independent modules to produce
an executable, regardless of the  license terms of these independent
modules, and to copy and distribute the resulting  executable under
terms of your choice, provided that you also meet, for each linked
independent module, the terms and conditions of the license of that
module. An  independent module is a module which is not derived from
or based on this library

http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html
